# What is in the VIP area in the main fleet cantina?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I know you need the wrist band from the Digital Deluxe or Collector's Edition to access it, but what is up there in that exclusive VIP area?

[image: view of the VIP lounge from the unprivileged cantina]

Comment: You can also buy access with a *ton* of credits.

Comment: Only 1 mil credits. Now everyone gets to be special. ;)

Comment: Now they can't be accused of being P2W

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It keeps the CE Elite (and the rich) away from common folk and provides a platform to dive off of if you're feeling suicidal.

There's a jukebox, a VIP vendor (that sells a 1.5 mil mount) and a CE Vendor (for CE characters, sells social gear and companion customizations), bartenders that sell buff food (and the VIP wristband).  With [Patch 1.7](http://www.swtor.com/patchnotes/1.7.0/return-gree) a GTN kiosk, mailbox, and cargo hold were also added.

Comment: A lot of angry SWOTR fans have complained about this, I've heard of rumours of more exciting content being added. Just a few whispers in the forums at the moment though.